# How to group/collect variables and keep IDE (PyCharm) highlighting?

Tags: python, pycharm

In Python, I often collect several variables that I use as parameters or settings into one container.

For instance, I often organize settings (or parameters or options) like

```
nr_of_users = 100
file_label = "copy"
```

into a dictionary, like so

```
options['nr_of_users']= 100
options['file_label']= "copy"
```

This makes it easy to print & review these parameters, and pass them between functions in chunks etc..., since they are all collected under one "handle".

And I can add fields as they come-up, without first defining a class and its members.

The issue with this approach is that my IDE doesn't recognize these as variables, and I miss out on variable highlighting (linking definition to use), and refactoring (renaming) support.

(My IDE is PyCharm, but I suspect it's not unique to this one)

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If you have a "closed set" of fields that you want to associate together, a class would likely be a much better option. That way you can't typo a string key, and you'll have proper refactoring support. Dictionaries disallow a lot of functionality because they're open to change.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, good tip. I tried 'class B:pass' and it seems that (static?) members are open: I can set B.x=3 outside the class definition, and use it. IDE recognizes it. Not sure how that is possible or what data construct this is. Shows up in dir(B), so this could actually be useful. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I meant define the members in the class itself, not "dynamically". I'm personally against "dynamic variables", because from my experience with them, they don't help readability. I can't really make suggestions because that isn't a practice I'm used to.